# Trying to get Text to Show up in Footer for Website

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I am having trouble with one of the parts of my website.

I used the same code that was used in the home page for the footer. I removed lines from the footer. When I removed the lines, it deleted the footer. It has something to do with the position however it is the exact same code I have in the home page. The home page has that same position and everything, therefore I am unsure what is happening.

If anyone has advice as to how I can fix the CSS to make the email show up in the about me page, that would be great!

Here is the CSS code:

Here is a link to my github which as both the html and css:
https://github.com/b3lla-c0rtez/b3lla-c0rtez.github.io
https://github.com/b3lla-c0rtez/about_bella

```
#home {
    position: absolute;
    right: 80%;
    top: 8px;
}
#about {
    position: absolute;
    right: 65%;
    top: 8px;
}

#websites {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 8px;
}

#projects {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35%;
    top: 8px;
}

#linked {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 8px;
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 8px;
}

.header {
    background: #f6cdff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}

h1 {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

button {
    background-color: #f6cdff; 
    border-width: 0; 
    color: black; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #a6a6a6; 
    border-width: 0; 
    color: black; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}

body {
    background-color: #adcde3;
}

h2 {
  margin-left:  40px;
  margin-top:  60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

img {
    margin-top:  65px;
    width: 292px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.parent{
    display:flex;
    gap: 18px;
}

footer {
    background: #f6cdff;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}

#email {
    font-size: 13px;
    bottom: 8px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin-left:  20px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

.opensans {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```
#home {
    position: absolute;
    right: 80%;
    top: 8px;
}

#about {
    position: absolute;
    right: 65%;
    top: 8px;
}

#websites {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 8px;
}

#projects {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35%;
    top: 8px;
}

#linked {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 8px;
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 8px;
}

.header {
    background: #f6cdff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}

h1 {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

button {
    background-color: #f6cdff; 
    border-width: 0; 
    color: black; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #a6a6a6; 
    border-width: 0; 
    color: black; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}

body {
    background-color: #adcde3;
}

img {
    float: right;
    margin-top:  65px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

footer {
    background: #f6cdff;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}

#email {
    font-size: 13px;
    bottom: 8px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin-left:  20px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

.opensans {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: paste your html code

Comment: Here is the link to the website, if you see the home page has my email in the footer however the about me page does not https://b3lla-c0rtez.github.io/

Comment: Your about page changes the styling of all p elements, which is affecting the footer.

Comment: just added the links to github which has the html code (stack overflow isn't letting me put both html file links)

Comment: there is email on both pages! explain more what is your problem with footer

Answer (score 0):

As dantheman mentions, You have `margin-top: 75px`  for all `p` tags (paragraphs).
Just to be doubly clear, Your email is inside a paragraph element.

It hasn't gone off-screen because something was deleted. It went off-screen because of the new styles targeting all paragraphs on the about page.

Adding another line to reset the `margin-top` for only the email should fix it.
Eg, when in your css, you target `#email` add a line saying `margin-top: revert;`.

```css
#email {
  font-size: 13px;
  bottom: 8px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: revert;
}
```

I'd recommend getting comfortable with your browsers DevTools, because it allows you to play with different values for css, as well as toggling individual style rules which are active on an element.

See [this page for more information](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/) about using DevTools to do css stuff. That specific page is about chrome DevTools, but in Edge or FireFox or Safari it's mostly the same. Just the way to open it, or the button layout might differ slightly. Also, that specific page is just the first in a short series of pages about using DevTools for css, and the [next page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/issues/) has some tips for debugging CSS issues.